# Update swiper effect with swiperjs react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm looking for a way to update the swiper's effect (and some other settings). I found out that we have to `swiper.destroy(true, true)` then init the swiper again (from [here](https://www.tutorialfor.com/questions-138198.htm) and [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1418)). Initializing the swiper like [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371162/how-to-initialize-swiper-using-react-hooks)

```
let mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     loop: true,
     slidesPerView: '2',
     centeredSlides: true,
     pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
     },
  });
```

return `Swiper is not a constructor` error as I supposed from my imported Swiper is from 'swiper/react' instead of just from 'swiper'. Any ideas how to fix this? or any other approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import Swiper, I would recommend storing it in a ref that way you're not constantly creating a new instance of Swiper on each render, you can do something like the following:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';

const MyComponent = () => {
 const swiperRef = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    swiperRef.current = new Swiper(
        '.swiper-container', // You can also use a ref to the element here
        {
          loop: true,
          slidesPerView: '2',
          centeredSlides: true,
          pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
          },
        },
    );

    return () => {
      swiperRef.current.destroy(true, true);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

You can now access swiper using `swiperRef.current`